# Stream of Results to Result of Vec: how to avoid multiple `into_iter`s and `collect`s?

Tags: rust

In the following Rust, I'm using one iteration+collection to turn a `Stream` of `Result`s into a `Vec` of `Results`, then another iteration+collection to turn the `Vec` of `Results` into a `Result` of `Vec`, while transforming the items. Can I do everything in one pass? I think this would be more succinct, readable, and possibly performant:

```rs
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
struct Thing {
    key: Option<i32>,
}


async fn _unused(stream: impl futures::Stream<Item = Result<Thing, ()>>) -> Result<Vec<i32>, ()> {
    let v = stream.collect::<Vec<Result<Thing, ()>>>().await;
    let v = v.into_iter().collect::<Result<Vec<Thing>, ()>>()?;
    Ok(v.into_iter().filter_map(|o| o.key).collect::<Vec<_>>())
}
```

Comment: Unlike `Iterator::collect`, doesn't look like `StreamExt::collect` can collect into a `Result`, so I don't think you can do it in a single pass. You can do it in two passes though, by transforming and unwrapping the value while iterating on the `v` then collecting directly into a `Result<Vec<_>, _>`. You can just use `match` to generate your mapping/filtering from `Result<Thing, ()>` to `Result<i32, _>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do something with the stream combinators, but you can always do it the good old imperative way:

```rust
async fn _unused(stream: impl futures::Stream<Item = Result<Thing, ()>>) -> Result<Vec<i32>, ()> {
    let mut success = Vec::new();
    let mut stream = std::pin::pin!(stream);
    while let Some(o) = stream.next().await {
        match o {
            Ok(o) => {
                let Some(v) = o.key else { continue };
                success.push(v);
            }
            Err(e) => return Err(e),
        }
    }
    Ok(success)
}
```

Comment: For this pattern I like to write `let o = o?;` as the first line of the loop, to avoid the match.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there is a way, using [`try_collect()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html#method.try_collect) of `TryStreamExt`:

```rust
use futures::stream::{StreamExt, TryStreamExt};

struct Thing {
    key: Option<i32>,
}

async fn _unused(stream: impl futures::Stream<Item = Result<Thing, ()>>) -> Result<Vec<i32>, ()> {
    stream
        .try_filter_map(|o| async move { Ok(o.key) })
        .try_collect()
        .await
}
```

Comment: This should be the answer. OP, please accept this one.